# How to get the details of a particular contact from the phone contact list?

Tags: android

what i want to do is i will provide a number and i want to get name by which that number is stored in the mobile contact list. I've tried many codes from different sites but none is fulfilling my requirement! I'm working on this since many hours any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Currently i'm using this code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL,  Uri.encode(incomingNumber));
        Toast.makeText(context, incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String name = null;
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri,new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME }, null, null, null);
                        Toast.makeText(context, p.getString(cursor.getString(0), "unknown"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // Invoke endCall()
                         if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                             editor1.putBoolean("fromcontacts", true);
                             editor1.putBoolean("notfromcontacts", false);
                             editor1.putString("incomingnumbername", cursor.getString(0));
                             editor1.commit();
                            // Toast.makeText(context, p.getString("incomingnumbername", "unknown"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }

                         else
                         {
                             editor1.putBoolean("notfromcontacts", true);
                             editor1.putBoolean("fromcontacts", false);
                             editor1.putString("incomingnumbername", "Unknown");
                             editor1.commit();
                     Toast.makeText(context, p.getString("incomingnumbername", "unknown"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get all the contacts and then loop and check for the name according to the given phone number

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                  String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                  String name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                  if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(
                        cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                     Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                               null,
                               ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?",
                               new String[]{id}, null);
                     while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                         String phoneNo = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                         Toast.makeText(NativeContentProvider.this, "Name: " + name + ",  Phone No: " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }
       }
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: It will consume a lot of time and i want those variables value in a second.